# Get username of a specific member from a telegram group

Tags: python, chat, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have recently created a telegram bot which has to store all the message information in database. right now I am trying to get the username of a specific member from a telegram group but I just could not do it. I have tried using the `update.message.chat.username` command but I can only get the username if the user sends personal message to the telegram bot. It is only showing 'none' when someone texts in the telegram group.

```
{'update_id': 186306520, 'message': {'channel_chat_created': False, 'text': 'd', 'entities': [], 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'date': 1664156166, '
group_chat_created': False, 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'caption_entities': [], 'message_id': 840, 'new_chat_members': [], 'chat': {'type': 'group', 'ti
tle': 'telebot', 'id': -681675725, 'all_members_are_administrators': True}, 'new_chat_photo': [], 'photo': [], 'from': {'first_name': 'Mr', 'id': 710699496, 'last_name': 'Dhai', 'is_bot': False, 'username': 'dhai1'}}}
```

I tried to use `print(update)` command this is the output I got so I just tried the `update.message.from.first_name;` command but I am getting errors since `from` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `from` is a reserved word in Python, `python-telegram-bot` uses `from_user` instead, i.e. `update.message.from_user.first_name`. This is also explained in the [docs of the `Message` class](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/telegram.message.html#telegram-message) :)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`